# Getting the area of a polygon using the overlay complete function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the area of a polygon, the issue is that the idea is that the user can draw several polygons.

At the moment when the overlaycomplete function fires I can't seem to figure out how to actually reference the polygon that was just made.

At the moment I have this...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
    all_overlays.push(e);
    if (e.type == 'polygon') {
        //get the coordinate array of your polygon
        var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(polygon.getPath());
        console.log(area);
        var overallArea = overallArea + area;
        console.log(overallArea);

        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

    }
});
```

So when the shape is completed the details of the shape is added to an array so that they can later be cleared from the map.

However, when I try and calculate the area I get this...

ReferenceError: polygon is not defined

What do I actually need to do in order to reference and therefore obtain the area of the most recently drawn shape/polygon?

Answer (score -2):

The Polygon is `e.overlay`.  Use that to compute the area:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
  all_overlays.push(e);
  if (e.type == 'polygon') {
      //get the coordinate array of your polygon
      var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(e.overlay.getPath());
      console.log(area);
      overallArea = overallArea + area;
      console.log(overallArea);

      // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wLf88679/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  var all_overlays = [];
  var overallArea = 0;
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['polygon']
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    all_overlays.push(e);
    if (e.type == 'polygon') {
      //get the coordinate array of your polygon
      var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(e.overlay.getPath());
      console.log(area);
      overallArea = overallArea + area;
      console.log(overallArea);

      // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```